# WiFi Card Issues, Dell Inspiron 1525 & Broadcom BCM4321

Tags: wireless, 17.10

So I run a VPN and a NextCloud server on Ubuntu 17.10 and while I know WiFi isn't the best solution, it's the best I can do as of now. The problem I am having is that randomly (or at least as I cannot pinpoint the issue), the WiFi card turns off and the only way of fixing this is turning WiFi off and on.

Now, is there any way of fixing this OR is there a command that I could run that could do this for me automatically?

Comment: 16.10 is no longer supported. Please use a supported release at all times.

Comment: My apologies, the 16.10 was incorrect. I am running 17.10.

Comment: If so, assure you have the correct driver - https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers - and WPA2-AES at the router.